# Battery voltage drops when connected to PCB

Tags: batteries, pcb, breadboard, 7805, atmega328p

I have a circuit containing an atmega328p microcontroller with hc-05 bluetooth module. microcontroller is powered via 7805 regulator. When 7805 is supplied the source voltage by a 9V battery, the circuit works fine on a breadboard, but the same circuit fails on a PCB. I have tried two different PCB designs, but they have the same problem. The battery input voltage falls from 9V to less than 1V. I have verified multiple times that the PCB design is the same as the breadboard design. Is that a fundamental rule to PCB designing that i am missing?

Comment: They are different instances of the circuit, so one could easily have a fault that the other doesn't. A PCB can easily slip a short-circuit through on you if you don't pay attention to what things touch the ground plane, beware metal tabs on ICs especially.

Comment: 1V on battery suggests there is almost certainly. a major error. Check check rerere-check regulator  Are you reversing polarity in the two designs. Note on TO220 tab is usually grounded on 7805. D o you have caps on Vin and Vout.? Oscilloscope says ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is that a fundamental rule to PCB designing that i am missing?

#### NO.

Simple as that.

There are, however, differences. The breadbord is pretty bad, from an electrical engineering perspective. It adds stray inductance, capacitance and resistance everywhere. This usually makes your circuit *worse*. In this case, maybe by pure luck, the exact same design on the PCB *oscillates* because it now lacks the stray capacitance and inductance, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Oscillation in a circuit can make things draw much more power than expected, but you won't be able to verify this easily without an *oscilloscope*¹. Without an oscilloscope you have limited means to debug this issue.

If you power this with a battery, it sounds to me that you don't have a well-equipped lab, but you do have a multimeter. I don't know what you mean by "verified" that the PCB and breadboard are the same, but you should check for shorts with a multimeter, not just look at the PCB.

<sub>1. pun not guaranteed</sub>